# Why can't I see why I got a close vote?

Tags: support, close-reasons

On [my latest question](https://superuser.com/questions/611256/im-using-a-shared-server-and-as-such-gmail-marks-my-email-as-spam-all-from-he), I got a close vote:

[image]

All I know is that I *got* a close vote, not *why*. I'd like to edit my question to prevent from getting more votes, is there a way to tell why I got it?

Comment: The question is off-topic. Probably better suited for [webapps.se]

Comment: @OliverSalzburg How'd you see the close reason? Also is it possible to migrate my own question?

Comment: I knew the question is off-topic without checking the close vote ;) Besides that, once you gain the privilege to vote to close, you can see which close reasons other people picked. Not sure if you can see the reasons any other way.

Comment: As question author you can probably click 'close (1)' to see what reasons others voted for -- you can see the link after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the appropriate vote-to-close privileges, you can simply click the `close` button yourself and a list of reasons should pop up.  I've just gone through your question and VTC'd it to get it migrated over to WebApps, but thank you for attempting to learn how to better phrase questions for Super User.

Before casting my vote, just so you're aware, this is the box I was shown:

---

[image]

---

As you can see, 4 people had already voted to close the question as off-topic.  If you then were to click off-topic, you would see the following list of sub-reasons (as well as where people voted to migrate the question if appropriate):

---

[image]

---

So you can see, 1 person voted to close the question as off-topic, and another 3 voted to move/migrate the question to WebApps.SE.  Questions only need 5 votes from non-moderators, so my final vote caused the question to finally be closed, and the majority reason for closing the question was taken (migrating over to WebApps.SE).